# Powershell 7.3.0 Tab completion not working

Tags: powershell, autocomplete, powershell-7.3

I've recently upgraded PowerShell to version 7.3.0 version and now, when I type a command, I see its suggestions like when I'm typing `pip` it adds `list` [like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYL2t.png). Or when I type start of the command it suggests its full name.

The problem is that when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it doesn't complete the command, instead it just starts listing current directories, i.e. here is an [image after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nkK6.png).
Also even when I start typing the full name of the command like `pip li` it still shows the ending, but when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> it just does nothing.

I expected this to complete the current command with the suggestion after <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed.

I've tried to google this problem but haven't found the exact same case I have with 7.3.0 version.

Comment: The command predictions are separate from tab completion. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-predictors?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Check out this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897570/5354229

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Just press <kbd>-></kbd> (right arrow) key

If you want to change key bindings:
source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/

> ## Key Bindings for Predictions
>
> Key bindings control cursor movement and additional features within the prediction. To support users running Predictive IntelliSense on multiple platforms, key bindings are user-settable from the command line or your profile script.
>
> `PSReadLine` contains functions to navigate and accept predictions. As an example, to accept a displayed prediction, PSReadLine contains functions:
>
> - AcceptSuggestion – Accept the current inline suggestion
> - AcceptNextSuggestionWord – Accept the next word of the inline suggestion
>
> `AcceptSuggestion` is built within `ForwardChar`, which by default is bound to <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> accepts an inline suggestion when the cursor is at the end of the current line.
>
> `AcceptNextSuggestionWord` is built within the function `ForwardWord`, which can be bound with Ctrl+f by `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "Ctrl+f" -Function ForwardWord`. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd> accepts the next word of an inline suggestion when the cursor is at the end of current editing line.
>
> As a user, you can bound other keys to `AcceptSuggestion` and `AcceptNextSuggestionWord` for similar functionalities. Search for `ForwardCharAndAcceptNextSuggestionWord` in `SamplePSReadLineProfile.ps1` for an example to make <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> accept the next word from inline suggestion, instead of the whole suggestion line.
>
> List of additional suggested key bindings defined in [`PSReadLine SamplePSReadLineProfile.ps1`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/master/PSReadLine/SamplePSReadLineProfile.ps1#L13-L21)

Comment: Thank you! Omg that was so simple, though not easy to find without knowing the name of the feature

Comment: Is it possible to change it to tab?

Comment: Before finding this StackOverflow question, I was wondering the same and made my little investigation. So I want to share my investigation process https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2022/11/21/powershell-predictive-intellisense/

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use :

`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Ctrl+q -Function TabCompleteNext`

i grabbed this line from ["this line in PSReadLine github"](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/ac69010fec57df06827aebb711d243706ec24e9b/PSReadLine/SamplePSReadLineProfile.ps1#L96C1-L96C63)