# How to change the Suggestion completion key on Powershell 7.3.0?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-7.3

Recently I updated my PowerShell to version 7.3.0 and when typing it shows suggestions. But when I press the Tab key it doesn't autocomplete the suggestion. How to set the `Tab` as the autocompletion key?

Comment: `TAB` is the auto complete key. You are looking for history complete witch is `right arraow`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So after doing some research I found out,

- The default autocompletion key is the `RightArrow` key.
- You can accept the suggestions word by word
- You can change the suggestion view type between `InlineView` and `ListView` by pressing `F2`

Source: [Using predictors in PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-predictors?view=powershell-7.3)

So here's how to change key bindings

Set `Tab` key as the keybinding for auto complete (AcceptSuggestion)

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "Tab" -Function AcceptSuggestion
```

Set `RightArrow` key as the keybinding for accepting the next word in the suggestion (ForwardWord)

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "RightArrow" -Function ForwardWord
```

Note :

You need to run these each time you open a new session. To avoid that add these to `profile.ps1` file. [More on Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3)

- To change these just for the current user,

  Open a PowerShell window and run,

  ```
  notepad $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
  ```

OR

- To change these for all users,

  Open a PowerShell window with `Run as Administrator` and run,

  ```
  Notepad $profile.AllUsersAllHosts
  ```

If the file doesn't exist, create a new one.

Add these lines and save.

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "Tab" -Function AcceptSuggestion
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "RightArrow" -Function ForwardWord
```

Comment: My F2 has no effect, how to fix it? I don't see F2 bound.

Comment: @KonstantinGlukhov did you fix it? I tried it on Jetbrains Rider's terminal and F2 did nothing, but I ran
```Get-PSReadLineOption | Select-Object -Property PredictionSource```
and it says
```WARNING: The prediction 'ListView' is temporarily disabled because the current window size of the console is too small. To use the 'ListView', please make sure the 'WindowWidth' is not less than '54' and the 'WindowHeight' is not less than '15'.
PredictionSource
----------------
HistoryAndPlugin```

After resizing the terminal's height, it worked.

Comment: Yes, I got it working. Just had to RFM. My problem was that I was using Vi mode and all the help pages are about emacs by default. To make it working in Vi mode you need to use the following "Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler F2 -Function SwitchPredictionView"

Comment: Want to throw out there for anyone reading that MS PowerToys has a keyboard manager, which allows you to rebind keys. For use in both Visual Studio (where right-arrow also does intellisense autocomplete) and Powershell 7, I mapped CapsLock to right-arrow to make life easier. Added side bonus of never having to worry about caps lock being on.

Comment: FWIW I get an error with the first command: "Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Function'. The argument "AcceptSuggestion" does not belong to the set [...]" where "[...]" is a list of actions "specified by the ValidateSet attribute".

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to switch the behaviors of `Tab` and `RightArrow`, use this:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "Tab" -Function AcceptSuggestion
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "RightArrow" -Function TabCompleteNext
```